# To prove $| S(f,P,T) - S(g,P,T) | \leq M(b-a)$ ( Riemann Integration)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, self-learning, riemann-sum

To prove $| S(f,P,T) - S(g,P,T) | \leq M(b-a)$

Question : Let $[a,b] \subseteq R$ be a non degenerative closed bounded interval and let $f,g :[a,b] \rightarrow R$ be functions .Suppose that there is some M belonging to N(natural numbers) such that $|f(x)-g(x)| \leq M$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ .Let P be a partition of $[a,b]$ and let T be a representative set of P .Prove that $| S(f,P,T) - S(g,P,T) | \leq M(b-a)$

**ATTEMPT**

[image]

[image]

**Firstly is this correct ? If this proof is correct ,this is for partition with equal widths ,what if the widths are not equal then how will proof be modified .Thanks**

Comment: Since I didn't read what you wrote, I'm making this a comment rather than an answer. (If you want it read, figure out how to MathJax it.) First rewrite $S(f,P,T)-S(g,P,T)$ as $S(f-g,P,T)$. Then use the triangle inequality and replace $|f(x_i)-g(x_i)|$ with $M$ in each summand. Then the widths of the subintervals sum to the length of the entire interval (regardless of how exactly they are spaced).